# Unable to set-up Libre office development environment

Tags: development-environment, libreoffice

I'm trying to setup up LoDe in Windows 10, where I'm installing it on the D:/ drive.
I'm following this link - https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/lode and whenever I 'run' the `./setup` command It freezes at - `Resolving www.nasm.us` 
Though I have checked with the `./setup --prereq` and `cat README` that I meet with all the perquisites. Here's the text from Cygwin.bat window

```
[username]@DESKTOP-[no.] /cygdrive/d/Files/Libre_office/lode
$ ./setup
Check directory 'packages' ... : Exist
Check directory 'opt' ... : Exist
Check directory 'ext_tar' ... : Exist
Check directory 'adm' ... : Exist
Check directory 'tb' ... : Exist
git repo '/cygdrive/d/Files/Libre_office/lode/adm/buildbot' exist
ant already installed
junit Already Installed
Check directory '/cygdrive/d/Files/Libre_office/lode/opt/bin' ... : Exist
--2018-03-25 13:09:03--  http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.11.06/win32/nasm-2.11.06-win32.zip
Resolving www.nasm.us (www.nasm.us)... 198.137.202.136, 2607:7c80:54:e::136
Connecting to www.nasm.us (www.nasm.us)|198.137.202.136|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to www.nasm.us (www.nasm.us)|2607:7c80:54:e::136|:80... failed: Network is unreachable.
/cygdrive/d/Files/Libre_office/lode/bin/utils_Cygwin.sh: line 35: module: parameter null or not set
```

Note: My internet is working perfectly and there are no speed fluctuations or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nasm.us seems to be down

edit "lode\bin\utils_Cygwin.sh"
replace

```
local pack_file="nasm-2.11.06-win32.zip"
local pack_dir="nasm-2.11.06"
local http_file="http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.11.06/win32/nasm-2.11.06-win32.zip"
```

with

```
local pack_file="nasm-2.12.02-win32.zip"
local pack_dir="nasm-2.12.02"
local http_file="http://mirrors.kodi.tv/build-deps/win32/nasm-2.12.02-win32.zip"
```

Comment: Will try it soon, Thanks